# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list <string> ' to 'string'

Tags: c#, methods, listviewitem

I have create a class containing a method to display the properties of a selected user in AD. When i try to call this method to put all the object in a listview i got the error.

Thanks for your help

```
class ProgramDisplayObjAD
{
    public static List<string> ComputersDisAD(string SelectedObjAD)
    {
        List<string> ComputerNamesList = new List<string>();

        DirectoryEntry DirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Backoffice,OU=BIO,DC=bio,DC=corpnet1,DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher MySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(DirEntry);

        MySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=" + SelectedObjAD + "))";

        foreach (SearchResult MyResult in MySearcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry ComputerName = MyResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

            Console.WriteLine("Computername : " + ComputerName.Properties["dNSHostName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Staging Date : " + ComputerName.Properties["whenCreated"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Operating System : " + ComputerName.Properties["operatingSystem"].Value);
        }

        DirEntry.Close();
        DirEntry.Dispose();
        MySearcher.Dispose();

        return ComputerNamesList;
    }

private void ListObjAD_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SelectedObjAD = ListObjAD.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (ComputerName.Checked)
        {
            ComputerPage.Text = SelectedObjAD;

            DisplayObjAD.SelectedTab = ComputerPage;

            //List<string> ComputersList = ProgramDisplayObjAD.ComputersDisAD(SelectedObjAD);

            ComputerItemList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { ProgramDisplayObjAD.ComputersDisAD(SelectedObjAD) };
        }
```

I know that the method works properly but i don't know how to displya the result in my listviewitem called: ComputerListDis.

Comment: This: `new string[] { ProgramDisplayObjAD.ComputersDisAD(SelectedObjAD) }` tries to create a string array with a single element, which is a `List<string>`. Did you just intend to convert the list to an array? If so, `ProgramDisplayObjAD.ComputersDisAD(SelectedObjAD).ToArray()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just what I wanted to suggest as an answer, I think it should be the answer. For the rest, I would advise the @userx to use the `using(DirectorySearcher MySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(DirEntry);` instead of disposing it manually. When an exception occurs, the instance isn't disposed.

Comment: Thanks, i have use the: "using(DirectorySearcher MySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(DirEntry);" i want to display all the properties of the object user with the method in a listviewitem called: "ComputerListDis" which is included in a tabcontrol: "ComputerTab".

Comment: I try this string[] ComputeryArray = ProgramDisplayObjAD.ComputersDisAD(SelectedObjAD).ToArray();

                ListViewItem ComputerListDis = new ListViewItem(ComputeryArray);
                foreach(string item in ComputeryArray)
                {
                    ComputerListDis.SubItems.Add(item);
                    ComputerItemList.Items.Add(ComputerListDis);
                } But that doesn't work